# What's the most efficient way to run cross-platform, deterministic simulations in Haskell?

Tags: performance, haskell, floating-point, floating-accuracy

My goal is to run a simulation that requires non-integral numbers across different machines that might have a varying CPU architectures and OSes. The main priority is that given the same initial state, each machine should reproduce the simulation exactly the same. Secondary  priority is that I'd like the calculations to have performance and precision as close as realistically possible to double-precision floats.

As far as I can tell, there doesn't seem to be any way to affect the determinism of floating 
point calculations from within a Haskell program, similar to the `_controlfp` and `_FPU_SETCW` macros in C. So, at the moment I consider my options to be

1. Use [Data.Ratio](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Ratio.html)
2. Use [Data.Fixed](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Fixed.html)
3. Use [Data.Fixed.Binary](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/fixed-point/latest/doc/html/Data-Fixed-Binary.html) from the [fixed-point](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fixed-point) package
4. Write a module to call `_ controlfp` (or the equivivalent for each platform) via FFI.
5. Possibly, something else?

One problem with the fixed point arithmetic libraries is that they don't have e.g. trigonometric functions or logarithms defined for them (as they don't implement the `Floating` type-class) so I guess I would need to provide lookup tables for all the functions in the simulation seed data. Or is there some better way?

Both of the fixed point libraries also hide the `newtype` constructor, so any (de-)serialization would need to be done via `toRational`/`fromRational` as far as I can tell, and that feels like it would add unnecessary overhead.

My next step is to benchmark the different fixed-point solutions to see the real world performance, but meanwhile, I'd gladly take any advice you have on this subject.

Comment: How diverse can the platforms be? On everything sensible, you should be fine with `Double`, using `-msse2` on 32-bit platforms (on by default on 64-bit).

Comment: Daniel Fischer: I don't need to support any esoteric platforms, but different (modern) flavors of Windows, Linux and MacOSX in both 32-bit and 64-bit. Reading [this page](http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/floating-point-determinism/) left me with the notion that just relying on sse2 instructions might not be sufficient in the Real World(tm) and that using fixed point arithmetic might be a lot less painful.

Answer (score 7):

Clause 11 of the IEEE 754-2008 standard describes what is needed for reproducible floating-point results. Among other things, you need unambiguous expression evaluation rules. Some languages permit floating-point expressions to be evaluated with extra precision or permit some alterations of expressions (such as evaluating `a*b+c` in a single instruction instead of separate multiply and add instructions). I do not know about Haskell’s semantics. If Haskell does not precisely map expressions to definite floating-point operations, then it cannot support reproducible floating-point results.

Also, since you mention trigonometric and logarithmic functions, be aware that these vary from implementation to implementation. I am not aware of any math library that provides correctly rounded implementations of every standard math function. ([CRLibm](http://lipforge.ens-lyon.fr/www/crlibm/) is a project to create one.) So each math library uses its own approximations, and their results vary slightly. Perhaps you might work around this by including a math library with your simulation code, so that it is used instead of each Haskell implementation’s default library.

Routines that convert between binary floating-point and decimal numerals are also a source of differences between implementations. This is less of a problem than it used to be because algorithms for converting correctly are known. However, it is something that might need to be checked in each implementation.